GEE: change in output resolution when reducing an image collection
I am attempting to reduce an image collection on GEE by getting the minimum value for each pixel, but when I use the min() function, GEE returns an image where the resolution is about 10x more coarse than the input data set. For instance, the code below returns a scale of 11,131 meters:
var dp = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY')
                .select('dewpoint_temperature_2m').first()
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-07-01', '2020-07-02'))
                .first();
var scl = dp.projection().nominalScale();
print('image scale:', scl);

But when I use min(), like below, it returns a scale of 111,319 meters:
var dp = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY')
                .select('dewpoint_temperature_2m')
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-07-01', '2020-07-02'))
                .min();
var scl = dp.projection().nominalScale();
print('image scale:', scl);

Does anyone know why GEE is making the resolution more coarse when using min()? (I get the same result using mean() and max() as well.) I've used GEE previously with different data sets, and I don't recall this occurring.

Reducers discard projection information and assume a default scale of 1x1 degree. You can restore the original projection information by storing the projection before the reduction and setting it with setDefaultProjection after the reduction. For example:
var dp = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY')
                .select('dewpoint_temperature_2m')
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-07-01', '2020-07-02'))
                .first();
var scl = dp.projection().nominalScale();
print('image scale:', scl);

// Store the unmodified projection of the first image
var original_proj = dp.projection();

var dp = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY')
                .select('dewpoint_temperature_2m')
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-07-01', '2020-07-02'))
                .min()
                // Reassign the projection after reducing
                .setDefaultProjection(original_proj);
var scl = dp.projection().nominalScale();
print('image scale:', scl);

With that said, even though Earth Engine says the nominal scale is 10x larger, you haven't actually lost any resolution. Scale in Earth Engine isn't determined until the moment you apply some processing or export data and provide a scale parameter.
